# SQL Server 2012 service crashed

Tags: sql-server

A few days back we had an instance we noticed that the SQL Server 2012 service crashed. This had happened for the first time in the past 3 years.

I got error logs but didn't the dump file... here few snippet from the log ..

```
2020-02-24 08:29:56.97 spid1933    A time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch -- type 4, bp 0000019438122E80, page 59:2950791, stat 0x109, database id: 5, 
allocation unit Id: 72057830066094080, task 0x0000011914900188 : 0, waittime 300 seconds, flags 0x40a038, owning task 0x0000000000000000. Not continuing to wait.
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000014C64E14D60  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    ***Stack Dump being sent to I:\MSSQL11.<name>\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0007.txt  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    * *******************************************************************************  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    *  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    * BEGIN STACK DUMP:  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    *   02/24/20 08:29:56 spid 1933  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    *  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    * Latch timeout  
2020-02-24 08:29:56.99 spid1933    *
```

Comment: The first thing i would see is output of `select @@version` command. In most cases this happens because SQL Server is not patched to latest SP/CU.

Comment: Here is the version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)   Aug 15 2017 10:23:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: I believe you have to log call with MS to get the dump analyzed. They can tell if you are hitting any bug or is it due to some other reason.

Comment: Thanks @Shanky . But can you please suggest what are general circumstances when SQL server service restarts itself.. We are suspecting nothing from our code.. any other factors or angle to it?

Comment: SQL Server restarting itself is not a much of concern as compared to it generating a dump and restarting it. There was some "severe" problem which forced SQL Server to generate dump and then restart as it found out restart is best way to come out of hung situation. If this has happened first time you may wait to see if this things happens again and then take an action.

Comment: Thank you @Shanky. We'll open tckt with MS and keep investigating ..